# Cannot resolve IHttpHandler

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, web-services, ihttphandler

For some reason when I am trying to create a class which implements IHttpHandler I cannot resolve IHttpHandler.

Statements like:

```
using System.Web;
```

are not helping either.

This is a class library project, I am following example here: http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020417.htm

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that you are [referencing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(VS.80).aspx) System.Web from you project.